# Do I ever need to removeItem from localStorage before setItem?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have this code:

The developer does a removeItem from local storage before a setItem.  It seems to me that there is no need for this but I am not 100% sure:

```
putCacheData = (): void => {
    this.data = {
        authenticated: this.authenticated,
        bearerToken: this.bearerToken,
        expirationDate: this.expirationDate,
        firstName: this.firstName,
        fullName: this.fullName,
        lastName: this.lastName,
        roleId: this.roleId,
        subjectId: this.subjectId,
        userName: this.userName
    };
    localStorage.removeItem('userData');
    localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(this.data));
}
```

Is there a possibility that the removeItem is needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they're absolutely no reason for that. If the variable already exists then it will be overwritten, so no need to remove before setting.

The only way it would make a difference is an exception during the stringification of `this.data` but unless there's something strange in those data (like a circular structure) it can't happen.